# Redirect logged in users from register view

Tags: django, django-forms

I want logged in user redirect to index when they attempt to go to the register form.
I manage to do to that, but I can't validate the register form when the a user who is not logged in complete it.

I have a custom view for signup:

```
class SignupView(UserPassesTestMixin, FormView):
    template_name = 'main/auth/register.html'
    form_class = forms.UserCreationForm

    def test_func(self):
        self.request.user.is_authenticated

    def handle_no_permission(self):
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            return redirect('main:index')
        return self.get(self.request)

    def get_success_url(self):
        redirect_to = self.request.GET.get`enter code here`('next', 'main:index')
        return redirect_to

    def form_valid(self, form):
        response = super().form_valid(form)
        form.save()
        email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
        first_name = form.cleaned_data.get('first_name')
        raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
        logger.info('Nuevo registro para email=%s a través de SignupView', email)
        user = authenticate(email=email, password=raw_password)
        login(self.request, user)
        form.send_mail()

        return response
```

methods 
`test_func(self)` and `handle_no_permission(self)` are used to test if the user is authenticated

but I think the problem is in `return self.get(self.request)` I use it to load the form but when I submit the form with correct data, it POST it to validate it, but just reload it again. I suppose I have to call `form_valid` but I can't figure out how.

Any help would be appreciated!! Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `dispatch` method of django CBV. Like below.

```
class SignupView(UserPassesTestMixin, FormView):
    template_name = 'main/auth/register.html'
    form_class = forms.UserCreationForm

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            return redirect('main:index')
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    # other methods
```

Comment: Thanks. It works!! I have to delete UserPassesTestMixin as in no longer required.

Answer (score 0):

This is function based views and its simple

```
views.py
```

---

### to register

```
def register(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(reverse('post_list'))
    else:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            user_form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST)
            if user_form.is_valid():
                new_user = user_form.save(commit=False)
                new_user.set_password(
                    user_form.cleaned_data['password1']
                )
                new_user.save()
                Profile.objects.create(user=new_user)
                return render(
                    request,
                    'account/register_done.html',
                    {'new_user': new_user}
                )
        else:
            user_form = UserRegistrationForm()
        return render(
            request,
            'account/register.html',
            {'user_form': user_form}
        )
```

forms.py

```
class UserRegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
password1 = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={
    'class': 'myfieldclass',
    'placeholder': 'Password ...',
    'type': 'password',
    'name': 'password'
}))
password2 = forms.CharField(label='Repeat Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={
    'class': 'myfieldclass',
    'placeholder': 'Repeat Password ...',
    'type': 'password',
    'name': 'password'
}))
username = forms.CharField(label='Username', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
    'class': 'myfieldclass',
    'placeholder': 'Username ...',
    'type': 'text',
    'name': 'username'
}))

email = forms.CharField(label='Email', widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={
    'class': 'myfieldclass',
    'placeholder': 'Email ...',
    'type': 'email',
    'name': 'email'
}))



class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('username', 'email')
    
    help_texts = {
        'username': '',
    }

def clean_password2(self):
    cd = self.cleaned_data
    if cd['password1'] != cd['password2']:
        raise forms.ValidationError(
            'Passwords dosent Matched.')
    return cd['password2']
```